# Find correct table number (Selenium IDE)

Tags: selenium

I have this command here in Selenium IDE to store a text in a variable:

Command: **storeText**

Target: **//div[@id='content-main']/form[2]/table[5]/tbody/tr[td[1][contains(text(), 'Purchase')]]/td[2]**

Value: **variableName**

As you can see, in this command it looks in the first column of the 5th table and search for the line where it says "Purchase" and stores the string content from the second column.

The problem is this: **table[5]**

There are some times where this table is not always the 5th table. So, I'd like to know if there is some way to search for this String that I'm looking for, but without the table number, so the command would first find the table number, and then find the string I'm looking for.

To make it easier, here is the HTML source of the page I'm doing my tests:
http://txtup.co/e9KYB

I accept suggestions to maybe do it in another way, what I need is to store the Purchase Type value that is in this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change table[5] to table. The full XPath will then be:

```
 //div[@id='content-main']/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[td[1][contains(text(), 'Purchase')]]/td[2]
```

Comment: Glad that I could help :)